# Brachistichrone problem with friction

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In this [Mathworld article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrachistochroneProblem.html) for the Brachistichrone problem, it is said that the following:

> $$\left(1+(y')^2\right)(1+\mu y')+2(y-\mu x)y''=0$$

Implies that:

> $$\frac{1+(y')^2}{(1+\mu y')^2}=\frac{C}{y-\mu x}$$

I'm not sure how they arrived at this step -- how could a second-order differential equation even be reduced to a first-order one? I thought maybe they had a reason to assume constant curvature, but constant curvature would actually mean:

> $$\frac{1+(y')^2}{(1+\mu y')^2}=\frac{C}{(y-\mu x)^2}$$

(which doesn't make sense, anyway, because setting $\mu=0$ does not return the differential equation for the standard, frictionless brachistichrone)

Comment: Looks like they multiplied by 1/(1+uy') cubed. Then put the sign in the constant as well as the acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $u=y-\mu x$ ,

Then $u'=y'-\mu$

$u''=y''$

$\therefore(1+(u'+\mu)^2)(1+\mu^2+\mu u')+2uu''=0$